# Facebook Flash app cannot communicate with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, facebook, facebook-actionscript-api

My index.php file loads the Facebook JavaScript SDK and the FBJS bridge:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="FBJSBridge.js"></script>
```

It then inits the Facebook SDK:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   FB.init({
     appId  : '<?=$fbconfig['appid']?>',
     session: <?php echo json_encode($session); ?>,
     status : true, // check login status
     cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
   });
```

And embeds the Flash file using swfobject:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.myserver.org/Facebook/app/app.swf", "holderDiv", "740", "616");
```

When I run this file on my server, I can communicate with Facebooks JavaScript SDK either indirectly through ExternalInterface calls, launching various Facebook UI dialogs etc. And I can also use the [facebook-actionscript-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/) to launch the same dialogs directly from ActionScript.

When I however use this index file as my Facebook canvas url and load the swf in a Facebook iFrame, the communication crashes the application. I'm not sure how to debug this but I think it might have to do with crossdomain security. Any ideas on debugging and/or solutions are welcome.

Comment: Add the iframe HTML and is the iframe href the same domain as the iframe parent? If not, then yes, it's a crossdomain thing, you don't have access to the iframe objects.

Comment: what do you mean with "crashes" exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FBJSBridge.js has been replaced in the updated 1.5 of the API. It's now in the AS3 source.

Answer (score 0):

It seems adding the parameter allowScriptAccess: "always" did the trick.
Strange this isn't mentioned in sample code applications ...

Answer (score 0):

here u can find a tutorial with source coad ===
[Communacation with Flash and javascript](http://hackpchack.blogspot.com/2014/03/as3-creating-facebook-application.html)